# Logic Pro X wont work as Rewire slave to Ableton

Tags: logic-pro, ableton-live

I have Ableton running and when I enable Rewire in Logic Pro x, apply changes and reload it I get an dialog box saying a `Rewire host is already running`...

I have tried both settings but cannot get it to work.

Ableton manual says pressing play should start and sync the slave, but this doesnt work.

Both DAWs are running in 64 bit mode.

Is there something I am missing to get logic to send audio to Ableton?

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about making Logic Pro X the ReWire slave, which means Logic will send sound into Ableton then that is not allowed by Logic Pro X. You can only receive sounds from Ableton into Logic.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Sandeep is correct that Ableton cannot be the Master to the slave Logic Pro X. Logic CAN be the master though, so the sound would be sent **to** logic **from** Ableton. Here is a link for that process: https://www.ableton.com/en/pages/rewire/logic_pro/

The important thing to note is that the master needs to be opened FIRST.

Then turn on ReWire

Then open the slave.

I have personally made Ableton as slave to Cubase,  as well as making Cubase a slave to Ableton, so I know it works there. Apple programs are always so finicky with outside things. They like to be in charge.